# Group and select last insert in a table

Tags: sql, mysql

I've a table to save some file with a simple versionning system like :

```
ID | FILENAME | CONTENT | DATE
1 | index.php | Content of index.php v1 | timestamp
2 | main.css| Some CSS content | timestamp
3 | index.php | Content of index.php v2 | timestamp
```

I need to code a SQL request to find in this table the last inserted content of each file.

For this, I tried to group and order by date but with this request :

```
SELECT * FROM modeles GROUP BY filename ORDER BY date DESC
```

but it didn't work because the order is done after the group and because the group take the first entry.

If someone here know the solution (this is probably easy but i don't know how to do...).

Thank you.

Comment: Whats nom_fichier in ur schema? The filename?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a Subquery

```
SELECT ID, FILENAME, CONTENT, DATE
FROM TABLE AS Main
WHERE ID = (SELECT MAX(Sub.ID) FROM TABLE AS Sub WHERE Sub.FILENAME = Main.FILENAME)
```

Optional `WHERE` if ID is not always the high on the last edited one_

```
WHERE DATE = (SELECT MAX(Sub.DATE) FROM TABLE AS Sub WHERE Sub.FILENAME = Main.FILENAME)
```